# How do I validate header parameters in compojure/swagger?

Tags: validation, clojure, swagger, compojure

Is there an idiomatic/best practices way to do the following in compojure-api:

The user calls our api with the following curl calls:

```
curl https://some/api/v1/example?a=b -H "u: userid" -H "p: auth-ticket"

curl -X PUT https://some/api/v1/other-example -d '{"c":"d"}' -H "u: userid" -H "p: auth-ticket"
```

I want to be able to send `u` and `p` to another (internal) service and validate whether they constitute an authorized/non-expired ticket.

I can check for the values in the middleware (wrapped using `wrap-routes`), but it latches on BEFORE the swagger/compojure validation that checks for the required presence of `u` and `p`.

I can't seem to find a way to sink the custom validation into the swagger/compojure validation.  Is there a good way to do this, or am I stuck validating before?

EDIT: I've done some more searching in the raw swagger, and I've found the idea of "Security Schema Objects" and "Authorizations", but I don't see any examples of how to use them with clojure/compojure.

EDIT: Code example.

```
(swag/GET* "/item/:item" 
  [item] 
  :summary "item" 
  :path-params [item :- (swag/describe s/Str "The item.")] 
  :description "Get the description of the item." 
  :header-params [ticket :- (swag/describe s/Str "security ticket")
                  userid :- (swag/describe s/Str "user ticket")]
  (ok (find-item item))

(swag/GET* "/item/:item/detailed" 
  [item] 
  :summary "item - detailed" 
  :path-params [item :- (swag/describe s/Str "The item.")] 
  :description "Get a detailed description of the item." 
  :header-params [ticket :- (swag/describe s/Str "security ticket")
                  userid :- (swag/describe s/Str "user ticket")]
  (ok (find-item item :detailed))
```

My problem is how do I avoid writing the `:header-params` section over and over again on **every** endpoint *and* throw an "Access Denied" if there's a missing ticket/userid or if it doesn't validate.

Comment: Are you using compojure-api or some library that includes swagger?

Comment: Using compojure-api.

Comment: I find your question confusing. As @santanu-dey suggested, I think you're a little confused with the role of swagger in this scenario. Swagger doesn't *do* validation - you typically need separate middleware for this, like `buddy` or `friend`. Either way, there's no reason a run-of-the-mill Ring middleware couldn't do what you're asking.

Comment: Right, my problem seems to be an intersection of Swagger and the Compojure-API.  I'll edit again to show off more of my problem.

Comment: What does  the namespace `swag` alias to? Is it `compojure.api.sweet`?

Answer (score 0):

Purpose swagger is to define the interface.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to define how the API will implement credential validation internally. This implementation details.

Swagger does not support defining implementation logic. It only allows defining the 'interface'

Comment: No, I expect swagger to allow me to say "Everything in this set of routes will accept these header parameters, and run the following function to short circuit after reading in the parameters, but before running the individual route's function."  Otherwise I have to define it in wrap-middleware (where nothing swagger has happened yet) or individually for each route (after Swagger has already kicked out coercion validation)

Comment: Okay. Think you can expect your implementation framework to do that. Node.js for example will allow doing that. Haven't seen this in swagger yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a combination of `context` and `:middleware`.

```
(swag/context "/item/:item" [item]
  :path-params [item :- (swag/describe s/Str "The item.")]
  :header-params [ticket :- (swag/describe s/Str "security ticket")
                  userid :- (swag/describe s/Str "user ticket")]
  :middleware [wrap-check-headers]

  (swag/GET "/" req
    :summary "item"
    :description "Get the description of the item."
    (ok (find-item item)))

  (swag/GET "/detailed" req
    :summary "item - detailed"
    :description "Get a detailed description of the item."
    (ok (find-item item :detailed))))
```

And you can define `wrap-check-headers` something like:

```
(defn wrap-check-headers [handler]
  (fn [{{:strs [ticket userid]} :headers :as request}]
    (if (and (= ticket "123") (= userid "456"))
      (handler request)
      (forbidden "authorization header mismatch"))))
```

This will produce a Swagger API that looks like:
[image: example swagger api]

And an API that behaves as desired:

```
$ curl -w '\nstatus:%{http_code}\n' -H Ticket:123 http://localhost:3000/item/abc/
{"errors":{"userid":"missing-required-key"}}
status:400

$ curl -w '\nstatus:%{http_code}\n' -H UserID:456 http://localhost:3000/item/abc/
{"errors":{"ticket":"missing-required-key"}}
status:400

$ curl -w '\nstatus:%{http_code}\n' -H Ticket:Wrong -H UserID:456 http://localhost:3000/item/abc/
authorization header mismatch
status:403

$ curl -w '\nstatus:%{http_code}\n' -H Ticket:123 -H UserID:456 http://localhost:3000/item/abc/
found ("abc")
status:200
```

Comment: @JonBristow I added Swagger screenshot and some example API behavior. Can you clarify what's wrong?

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to play around with this, but since I no longer work on this project it may be a while before I can confirm this works for me (and it might be that the version we were talking about is more out of date than it was at the time.)